# When i use bidimesional arrays the array begins with lines 0 and then 3

Tags: c++

I just started working with bidimensional arrays but my array starts like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fg9w.png)
and it looks like the array has assigned every falue i give to him even if i can't see it in the debugger.
Can anyone tell me what happens please and how should i fix it?
Here's the code even if I don't think there's any problem in it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
ifstream fin("a.in");
int main()
{
    int n,z;
    int v[50][50];
    fin>>n>>z;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            fin>>v[i][j];

    }
    int p=0;
    if(z==1)
    {
        if(n%2==0)
        {
            for(int i=2; i<n-1; i++)
            {
                p=p+v[1][i];
            }
            for(int i=3;i<n-2;i++)
            {
                p=p+v[2][i];
            }
            cout<<p;
        }
        if(n%2==1)
        {
            for(int i=2; i<n-3; i++)
            {
                p=p+v[0][i];
            }
            for(int i=3;i<n-3;i++)
            {
                p=p+v[1][i];
            }
            cout<<p;
        }
    }
    if(z==2)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<n-1; i++)
            {
                p=p+v[i][n-1];
            }
            for(int i=2;i<n-2;i++)
            {
                p=p+v[i][n];
            }
            cout<<p;
    }
    if(z==3)
    {
        for(int i=2; i<n-2; i++)
            {
                p=p+v[n-2][i];
            }
            for(int i=3;i<n-3;i++)
            {
                p=p+v[n-1][i];
            }
            cout<<p;
    }
    if(z==4)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<n-1;i++)
            {
                p=p+v[i][0];
            }
            for(int i=2;i<n-2;i++)
            {
                p=p+v[i][1];
            }
            cout<<p;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

PS.
my in file looks like this:
5 4
7 4 8 5 10
7 7 10 2 2
1 2 8 8 4
9 9 5 3 2
3 6 7 1 7
But the program shows me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbZye.png)

Comment: Since your question is about your debugger, you should say which debugger you are using (I don't recognise it from the screen shot).

Comment: GDB/CDB debugger

Comment: `gdb` and `cdb.exe` are two different debuggers?

Comment: I don't know :(

Comment: Did you mean `for(int i=0; i<n; i++) for(int j=0; j<z; j++) fin>>v[i][j];` NOTE the use of `z` for the `j` loop?

Comment: no, it's a square array with n

Comment: maybe it was just a bug cause after a little playing with the code it works

Comment: Your square 2D array is read into memory correctly. The result of your code is `19` -- how is that wrong? (and yes, `gdb` and `cdb.exe` are two completely unrelated debuggers, the first is the GNU debugger, the second is the VS debugger `:)`

Comment: true the result is good (that's why I said it might be a bug

Comment: You may clarify what you want to obtain with your code..

Comment: nothing specific I just saw that this bug is repeating and i wanted to know if it's something bad